# Clearing an app's *cache* and not the app's *data* via pm (or other CLI utility)?

Tags: root-access, command-line, cache

I'm running Android 13 in a rooted environment, and I want to use `pm` or some other Android command-line utility to clear an app's cache.  If I do `pm clear package.name`, it clears the app's data, and that's not what I want ... I only want cache clearing with the app's data remaining intact.

This needs to be a command-line utility, because I want to run it within a Tasker task. It could also be a shell script that runs multiple CLI commands.

I know that I can do `pm trim-caches [... args ...]` to clear all caches of all apps, but that's not what I want, either. I want to clear the cache of one and only one app at a time.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOPS! I originally overlooked the answer when checking the `pm` help text.

All I have to do is `pm clear --cache-only package.name`.

Comment: this command is not work, it will still clear UserData.

Comment: This command only clears the cache on my Android 13 device, and UserData is left intact.